# How to continue playing a capture device when the device is replugged in?

Tags: c#, usb, detection, video-capture, directshow.net

OK,I'm now developing a winform app that can capture stream from a video capture device using DirectShow.NET.
  And the problem is when I plug the usb capture device out. the image freezes,and after trying to stop , **my code hungs on IMediaControl.Stop()** method. Thus i can't continue playing. 
So is there a way to stop the playing progress when device is plugged out? or how to replay after the device replugs in?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no well-defined behavior for scenario with unplugged device. Eventually this should result in certain error code, however a delay with timeout might be involved. The behavior is dependent on actual implementation on the underlying filter backed by hardware driver.